# Append (alter) each array element via parameter expansion (i.e. without printf)?

Tags: zsh, string, array, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

Let the script below exemplify my quandary..

```
#!/bin/zsh

STUFF=( moose-hoof ovary clydsedale )

echo ${MINE=$(printf "MY-%s " $STUFF)}
echo ${MINE_EXP=${STUFF/^/MY-}}
```

> MY-moose-hoof MY-ovary MY-clydsedale
>
> moose-hoof ovary clydsedale

What are the right expansion flags to allow string concatenation on each element of the array?

Answer (score 20):

Use `$^array`.

It turns the array into a sort of brace expansion of the array. As in when `a=(foo bar baz)`, `$^a` would be a bit like `{foo,bar,baz}`.

```
$ a=(foo bar baz)
$ echo prefix${^a}suffix
prefixfoosuffix prefixbarsuffix prefixbazsuffix
```

For *multiplexing* arrays:

```
$ a=(1 2 3) b=(a b c)
$ echo $^a$^b
1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 3a 3b 3c
```

Naturally, if the prefix or suffix contain shell special characters (like `;` that separates commands or space that separate words, or `$"'&*[?~`...), they must be quoted:

```
echo 'p r e f i x '$^a' s u f f i x'
```

same as for `csh`'s (and bash, ksh, zsh's):

```
echo 'p r e f i x '{foo,bar,baz}' s u f f i x'
```

`$^a` itself must not be quoted, `"foo${^a}bar"` would expand as *one* word. One case where you would want `$^array` to be quoted, the same as for `$array` is when you want to preserve empty elements. Then, you need to quote the array expansion and use the `(@)` flag or the `"${array[@]}"` syntax (reminiscent of the Bourne shell's `"$@"`):

```
$ array=(x '')
$ printf '<%s>\n' $array         # empties removed
<x>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$array"       # array elts joined with spaces
<x >
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${(@)array}"  # empties preserved
<x>
<>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$array[@]"    # empties preserved
<x>
<>
$ printf '<%s>\n' $^array$^array # empty removed
<xx>
<x>
<x>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$^array$^array" # concatenation of joined arrays
<x x >
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$^array[@]$^array[@]" # multiplexing with empties preserved
<xx>
<x>
<x>
<>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me.. `echo "number ${^$(seq 3)} "` ->
`number 1`
`2`
`3` or `Z=( $(seq 3) ); echo "number ${^Z}"` ->
`number 1 2 3`

Comment: @don_crissti Only after trying your latter suggestion, `echo "number "${^$(seq 3)}""` would it work.  i have NEVER seen double quotes inside double quotes like that.  VERY weird.  VERY hard to remember.. but thanks!

Comment: @alexgray it's not quotes within quotes, it's the prefix and suffix being quoted, but not `${^(seq 3)}`, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

while this is a fairly old thread, i wanted to add a recent discovery of mine to do the same thing with [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) replace:

> ```
> ${name/pattern/repl}
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **The pattern may begin with a ‘#’, in which case the pattern must match at the start of the string, or ‘%’, in which case it must match at the end of the string**, or ‘#%’ in which case the pattern must match the entire string. The repl may be an empty string, in which case the final ‘/’ may also be omitted. To quote the final ‘/’ in other cases it should be preceded by a single backslash; this is not necessary if the ‘/’ occurs inside a substituted parameter. Note also that the ‘#’, ‘%’ and ‘#% are not active if they occur inside a substituted parameter, even at the start.

this allows to match a pattern at the start / end of the string and as there is no constrain to have a pattern only with `#` or `%` it can be used for prefixing and suffixing arrays:

```
$ array=(foo bar baz)
$ echo ${array/#/prefix_}
prefix_foo prefix_bar prefix_baz
$ echo ${array/%/_suffix}
foo_suffix bar_suffix baz_suffix
```

while certainly not as handy for string as they can be manipulated more easily, it's still doable:

```
$ string="bar"
$ echo ${string/#/foo_}
foo_bar
$ echo ${string/%/_baz}
bar_baz
```